# Is it always possible to partition $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ into disjoint blocks $D_{ij}$ s.t. $\left.f\right|_{D_{ij}}$ is bijective?

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, partitions

Consider the function given by $f:[a,b]\times[c,d]\to[0,1]^{2}$ such that $0\leq a < b \leq 1$, $0 \leq c < d \leq 1$.

Moreover, we do also have that $f\in C^{1}([a,b]\times[c,d],[0,1]^{2})$ and it is surjective.

**My question**

Is it always possible to partition $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ into disjoint blocks $D_{ij} = [x_{i},x_{i+1}]\times[y_{j},y_{j+1}]$, where $1\leq i \leq m$ and $1\leq j\leq n$, such that $\left.f\right|_{D_{ij}}$ is bijective?

If so, is there a minimum number of blocks $D_{ij}$ that satisfy this restriction?

Here I assume the function $f$ is not constant anywhere and $|f^{-1}(\{(x,y)\})| < N$ for every $(x,y)\in[0,1]^{2}$.

Such question is not homework. It came up from my personal research.

If this question is not adequate to this site, please let me know.

**EDIT**

The follow-up question to this is addressed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369511/under-which-conditions-the-domain-of-the-surjective-function-fa-b-timesc-d).

Comment: Please wait longer than one hour before you cross post (mathematics is patient), and please edit the other question to let people know about the cross posting.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will keep just this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

E.g., let $[a,b]=[c,d]=[0,1]$ and
$$f(x,y):=(g(x),y)$$
for $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$, where
$$g(x):=c\,h(x),$$
$$h(x):=x^p (1+a \sin\ln x)$$
for $x\in(0,1]$ with $h(0):=0$,
$$p\in(1,\infty),\quad1>a>\frac p{\sqrt{p^2+1}},\tag{0}$$
and $c:=1/\max_{x\in[0,1]}h(x)$. Then $f$ is a surjective $C^1$ map from $[0,1]^2$ to $[0,1]^2$.

Also, for any $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$, any $u\in(0,1]$, and any $v\in[0,1]$ the equality $f(x,y)=(u,v)$ implies $y=v$ and
$$\Big(\frac{u/c}{1+a}\Big)^{1/p}\le x\le\Big(\frac{u/c}{1-a}\Big)^{1/p}$$
and hence
$$\frac{\ln(u/c)}p-\frac{\ln(1+a)}p\le \ln x\le\frac{\ln(u/c)}p-\frac{\ln(1-a)}p,\tag{1}$$
so that $\ln x$ varies by at most $\frac{\ln(1+a)}p-\frac{\ln(1-a)}p=O(1)$ uniformly in $u\in(0,1]$.

Also,
$$g'(x)=cx^{p-1} [p+a (p \sin\ln x+\cos\ln x)] \\
=cx^{p-1} [p+a\sqrt{p^2+1}\,\sin(t+\ln x)]\tag{2}$$
for some real $t$ (depending only on $p$ and $a$) and all $x\in(0,1]$.

So, given the condition (1), $g'(x)$ can change the sign no more than $n$ times, for some natural $n$ depending only on $p$ and $a$. Therefore, $|f^{-1}(u,v)|\le n+1$ for any $(u,v)\in(0,1]\times[0,1]$. Also, $f^{-1}(0,v)=\{(0,v)\}$ for any $v\in[0,1]$. So, $|f^{-1}(u,v)|\le n+1$ for any $(u,v)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

On the other hand, it follows from (2) and (0) that $g'$ changes the sign infinitely many times in any right neighborhood of $0$. Therefore, the restriction of $f$ to any rectangle with a vertex at $(0,0)$ is not bijective.

---

For an illustration, below are the graphs $\{(e^{-1/t},\ln h(e^{-1/t}))\colon0<t<1\}$ (left) and $\{(e^{-1/t},\ln h(e^{-1/t}))\colon0<t<0.1\}$ (right) for $p=3/2$ and $a=9/10$. These graphs are non-linearly rescaled (horizontally and vertically, for better perception) versions of a graph of the function $h$ in a right neighborhood of $0$.

[image]

Comment: Nice example, it is 1d. I guess you use $p>1$ and $\log$ to get $C^1$ up to $0$. Do functions $x^p(1+a \sin x^{-q})$ work? For example $p=q=1$ (even though is not $C^1$).

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune : The example indeed shows that the 2D setting in the OP can be essentially reduced to 1D. As for the functions you are suggesting, they will not work, because then $|f^{-1}(u,v)|$ will be unbounded (as $u\downarrow0$) -- cf. (1), which is the crucial observation. ($C^1$ is not a big problem.)

Comment: In the first place, thanks for the contribution. Since it is not always possible to construct such partition, I'd like to know if there are additional restrictions which we could impose so that the wanted partition exists.

Comment: @BrickByBrick : Since your question has been fully answered, I think that, for more reasons than one, any further questions should be posted separately.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thanks for the suggestion. I will ask it separately.

Comment: Thank you, I see. The use of the $\log$ is crucial in combination with a power.